# Is there a way to replace non-apostrophed words to apostrophed ones? Ex. "Im" to "I'm"

Tags: javascript

TLDR: I need user input to be equal to the slug in the api. User input is "Im good", which converted to slug would be "im-good". Slug in the api is "i-m-good". How can I get a string like "i-m-good" with a user input like "im good"? Or more easily, is there a way to convert strings like "im good", "theres someone", "heres johnny" in "i'm good", "there's someone", "here's johnny"?

Hello everybody, let me explain what I'm trying to achieve.

I'm building a searchbar function for my app, and it has an input and some suggestions that appear after user types something. The logic for the suggestion is as follows: user types something, something gets converted to a slug, fetch request is sent to api to get said slug.

The problem occurs when an user wants to search something like "I'm good", or "There's something wrong", but they type "im good" or "theres something wrong" or stuff like that. As you can see, in both the examples there's an apostrophe which is omitted by the user, and while the slug called to the backend should be "i-m-good", the user input converted to slug by my function will be "im-good", therefore not fetching any data.

I thought about two different possible solutions (they both suck for different reasons):

1. calling all data from api and then filterng it based on user input (which will be converted into a string with only characters (like: userInput = im good, userInputCharOnly = "imgood")) and checked to see if it matches the slug of any entry of the result of the fetch (the slug would be converted to an only-character format too of course, so: slug = "i-m-good", slugCharOnly = "imgood"). This may work, but it would be way too resource intensive on my server, so I kinda hate this approach.
2. hardcoding the various possible strings which may be written by users and editing the user input before it gets passed to the api for the call (so if the user types "im good", the function would convert it to "i'm good" and then pass it to the toSlug() function. This is a better solution resource-wise, but I would be a bit ashamed of coding something like that, it really doesn't seem right.

So both solutions are not ideal. Is there a way to do what I want to do in an easier way that I did not think about? With regex maybe? Really any solution that would help me do that would be really appreciated.

Sorry for the wall of thext, and thanks!

Comment: How about using a NLP processor to fix the grammar? https://rapidapi.com/collection/grammar-spellcheck-api

Comment: How are you filtering slugs on your API? Do you have control of the API implementation? Are you reading them from a database?

Comment: Or simply enable the spellcheck attribute on the input.  The browser will flag "im"as a misspelling so that the user may correct it.

Comment: "*user types something, something gets converted to a slug, fetch request is sent to api to get said slug.*" - why do you convert to the slug on the frontend where you don't know whether you need to make a guess at correcting the input? Just send the raw user input to the backend, then do the appropriate search amongst the actually available slugs in there.

Comment: I probably should've said that in the original post, but I'm using Strapi as the backend, the feature basically works like so: user input gets converted to slug > api request is sent with a query like this: /api/article?filters[slug][$includes]=slug from user, and Strapi sends back the data from this query (from a database, yes). There's more logic than that, but this should be enough to give you all an idea of how the fetch works.

Comment: I do have control over API implementation, I can make custom requests to Strapi (i.e I implemented a viewsCount which calls a custom api route ), but I'm not great at doing stuff on the backend, that's why I was trying to keep this functionality on the frontend, but it seems like I don't really have many options here.

Comment: This may require use of a NLP library that understands context. Otherwise, how would you know whether to replace `its` with `it's` or `were` with `we're`? They're both correct depending on the rest of the sentence.

Comment: @Bergi the honest reason is that I wouldn't know how to do that :( 
How would you setup the logic on the backend, just to have something to work with and do some research about?

Comment: @PeterThoeny, Barmar
This seems like something I should give a look at, I'll read more about how to implement it in my project, thank you!

Comment: @GiovanniBeccaro That depends a lot on how your backend is currently resolving those slugs. In essence, you'd probably do something similar to the approaches you already described, but simply have the code run in the backend where it's much more efficient to load the required data.

Comment: @Yogi it sounds like an interesting option, but I doubt a spellcheck would be enough for most users, as most of them won't even be english speakers and would just want to search for song titles (that's what the app is for) typing carelessly

Comment: @Bergi Ok, so are you talking mainly about performance or is it better for a "spellchecking" perspective? Like, could I implement a more solid logic to check for errors in spelling in the backend, maybe a NPL library as others have suggested? Or is there some other check/logic to implement in the backend that you thought about?

Comment: @GiovanniBeccaro Not thinking of anything specific here, though depending on your backend implementation you may indeed have nicer/faster/more solid libraries available. But rather it's easier to implement a proper fallback algorithm: how do you know that `im-good` doesn't actually exist as a slug? You should check first, and only when you don't find it, attempt to correct it to `i-m-good`. If you were to have both, users would be really annoyed if you "fixed" it for them to always arrive at the second.

Comment: @Bergi Ok, I think I got your way of thinking, thanks for all the tips!

Comment: This is an interesting problem, but I still voted to close because the scope of the question is too broad and there aren't enough details.  Ultimately, this is a task better done with a database having full and fuzzy text matching, along with indexing and ranking, and in multiple languages.  For an example, see [Bleve](https://blevesearch.com/)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach is to remove all characters that are not letters or digits when generating a slug in the first place. This way, apostrophes, colons, dots, commas and other stuff will not matter.

Sample code:

```
const input = `I'm your master, don't    you see`;

const regexRemoveSpecial = /[^\p{Ll}\p{Lu}\p{Nd} ]+/gu;
const regexReplaceSpace = / +/gu;

let result = input;
// Remove everything except letters, digits and space
result = str.replace(regexRemoveSpecial, "");
// Replace space with underscore
result = result.replace(regexReplaceSpace, "_");
// Make lowercase
result = result.toLowerCase();

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

Output:

```
"Substitution result: ", "im_your_master_dont_you_see"
```

Use the same function when generating the slug for entries in your database and on search terms entered by your users.